# VBscript to delete subfolders

Tags: vbscript

I am very new to vb script and i need a script to delete couple of thrid level subfolders based on starting name _SA and 2 days old

example

C:\abc\user1\temp\ _SA123
c:\abc\user2\temp_SA2345
c:\abc\user3\temp_SA4567

I want to delete the folder starting with _SA older than 2 days and I have 50+ users folder. please hlep

Thanks,
Chilli

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the example data, this should work though I'd consider this the 4th level:

Edit: Because you asked nicely, I updated this to build a log in a variable that will list the path of the folder deleted, the date it was created, and the date you deleted it. This information shows up in a msgbox, but you could easily modify to print the data to a file instead.

```
Dim rootFolder
Dim fld
Dim subFld
Dim subsubFld
Dim Log
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rootFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\abc\")
For Each fld In rootFolder.SubFolders
    For Each subFld In fld.SubFolders
        For Each subsubFld In subFld.SubFolders
            If Len(subsubFld.Name) >= 3 Then
                If Left(subsubFld.Name, 3) = "_SA" And subsubFld.DateCreated < Now() - 2 Then
                    Log = subsubFld.Path & ", Created " & subsubFld.DateCreated & ",Deleted" & Now & vbNewLine
                    subsubFld.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
MsgBox Log
'Or you could print the log to a file.
```

It has no error trapping, (other than making sure the folder name is atleast 3 characters long) and will get permission denied if you don't have permission.

Note: the code I posted has indentations, it's just not display for some reason. If you want to see the indented code, hit the edit button.

Comment: Thank you verymuch. Really appriciate!!!. if possible can you please include the report for deleted folder details and number of days old.